# ERRO: Invalid floating point operation; mas especificamente quando coloca o ultimo sexo igual a "m"

Tags: visualg

```
algoritmo "Tarefa 11"

var
p, i, c, c2, d : inteiro
altura, maioraltu, menoraltu, mediamu, mediap, percen : real
s : caractere

inicio
      escreva("numero total de pessoas entrevistadas: ")
      leia(p)

  maioraltu := 0
  menoraltu := 99999

  para i de 1 ate p faca
       escreva("qual a altura da pessoa: ")
       leia(altura)
       escreva("qual o Sexo: ")
       leia(s)

       mediap := mediap + altura

       se altura > maioraltu entao
          maioraltu := altura
       senao
            se altura <= menoraltu entao
               menoraltu := altura
            fimse
       fimse

       se (s = "f") entao
          c := c + 1
          mediamu := mediamu + altura
       senao
            se (s = "m") entao
               c2 := c2 + 1
            fimse
       fimse
       
  fimpara

  mediamu := mediamu / c
  mediap := mediap / p
  percen:= c2 / p

  escreval("Maior altura:", maioraltu)
  escreval("Menor altura:", menoraltu)
  escreval("Altura média das mulheres:", mediamu)
  escreval("Altura média da população:", mediap)
  escreval("Percentual de homens:", percen)
```

Fimalgoritmo

Answer (score 0):

O problema está nas divisões após o laço de repetição. Eventualmente algum dos denominadores está igual a zero. Nesses trechos:

> ```
>   fimpara
>
>   mediamu := mediamu / c
>   mediap := mediap / p
>   percen:= c2 / p
> ```

Como sabido, os computadores não se dão muito bem com divisões por zero. Se ***c*** ou ***p*** for igual zero, dará erro. Daí se faz necessário "proteger" as divisões. Algo como:

```
   se (c <> 0) entao
      mediamu := mediamu / c
   fimSe

   se(p <> 0) entao
      mediap := mediap / p
      percen:= c2 / p
   fimSe
```

Obs.: outros ajustes precisam ser feitos no código, mas em relação ao erro seria isso.